# channel renaming usercase on a chatbot build using dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am trying build a bot where a user asks for services such as renaming a channel or password reset on a social platform.
consider that I want to rename a channel on slack and I enter the query as " I want to rename the channel rockers1.0 to rockers2.0 " . I have the " rockers1.0" name already in my entity list but not " rockers2.0 " as it is a new name . I am not able to find a mechanism by which i can identify the new name being mentioned.

Comment: Hi, please be more specific about what you want to do. Which tools and library do you use? What's your problem exactly? Is it a bug from a library? Do you need guidance? Do you already have some code?

Comment: I guess what he's asking for is either lazy polling or active websocket connections to stay up-to-date

Comment: consider that I want to rename a channel on slack and I enter the query as " I want to rename the channel rockers1.0 to rockers2.0 " . I have the " rockers1.0" name already in my entity list but not " rockers2.0 " as it is a new name . I am not able to find a mechanism by which i can identify the new name being mentioned.

Comment: Please update your question to include screen shots of the Dialogflow Intents you've configured, code that you are using as part of the webhook fulfillment, and other examples that illustrate what you're doing, what you expect, and what you're getting instead that is causing the problem. This helps us help you figure out what you're doing and how you can correct it.